# Javafx run fx thread in foreground and own thread in background

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a JavaFX application which reads tags and then puts them in a VBox list with HBox (label and button). However the application is very slow when there are a lot of tags to process. How can I optimize this process? The other problem I have is that the cursor and application are stuck/sleeping when it is loading/processing new tags, can I somehow fix this so the Thread runs in the background and I can still use my application?

My own thread:

```
    package nl.fermrfid.application.rfidreader;

    import javafx.application.Platform;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

    public class RFIDThread implements Runnable
    {
        /**
         * The socket for the connection to the LLRP Reader
         */
        private Socket socket;

        private JSONArray valid_tags;

        private JSONArray found_tags;

        private TagsListController controller;

        private RFIDSet rfidset;

        /**
         * Thread for constant reading of the stream
         * 
          * @param socket
          * @param controller
          * @param tags
         */
        public RFIDThread(Socket socket, TagsListController controller, JSONArray tags, RFIDSet rfidset) {
             this.socket = socket;
             this.controller = controller;
             this.rfidset = rfidset;
             this.found_tags = new JSONArray();
             this.valid_tags = tags;
        }


         /**
          * Runnable for this thread.
          * First get all the found tags from the xml controller
          * Then loop over the rfid set to find any new tags.
          * If there are any, display them.
          */
        @Override
        public void run()
        { 
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                while (!socket.isClosed()) {
                    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Tag> set = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
                    set.addAll(this.rfidset.getSet());

                        Collection<String> found_set = FXCollections.observableSet();

                        this.found_tags.clear();

                        for(Node n : this.controller.found_tags_box.getChildren()) {
                            this.found_tags.add(n.getId());
                        }

                        for (Tag found_tag : set) {
                            String tag_id = found_tag.getId();
                            if (found_tags.indexOf(tag_id) < 0) {
                                found_tags.add(tag_id);
                                found_set.add(tag_id);
                            }
                        }

                        Platform.runLater(() -> controller.addAllFoundTags(found_set));

                    pause(2000);
                }
            }
        }


        /**
         * Close the socket
         */
        public void shutdown()
        {
           try {
               this.socket.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }

        private void pause(long ms)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(ms);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The start thread method to start my own thread:

```
/**
     * Start the rfid thread
     * @param rfidset
     * @param action
     * @param textOrder
     */
    public void startThread(RFIDSet rfidset, Action action, String textOrder)
    {
        String readerId = RFIDApplication.getContext().getProperties().getProperty(SETTINGS_READERS);
        String host = RFIDApplication.getContext().getProperties().getProperty(String.format(SETTINGS_READER_HOST, readerId));
        String port = RFIDApplication.getContext().getProperties().getProperty(String.format(SETTINGS_READER_PORT, readerId));
        this.rfidset = rfidset;
        this.action = action;
        this.textOrder = textOrder;

        // Preparing management server instance ...
        this.server = RFIDApplication.server;

        // Preparing RFID reader instance ...
        this.reader = RFIDApplication.reader;

        try {
            thread = new RFIDThread(new Socket(host, Integer.parseInt(port)), this, valid_tags, rfidset);
            new Thread(thread).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The method which is called when new tags are found and need to be put in the list. It is a very ugly method.

```
public void addAllFoundTags(Collection<String> tags)
    {
        for(String tag_id : tags) {
            Integer index = valid_tags.indexOf(tag_id);

            Label label = new Label(tag_id);
            label.setTextFill(index >= 0 ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);

            Image cancel = new Image("/cancel.png", 14, 14, false, false);
            Button butt = new Button();
            butt.setGraphic(new ImageView(cancel));
            butt.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");

            butt.setOnAction(event -> {
                for (Tag tag : rfidset.getSet()) {
                    if (tag.getId().equals(tag_id)) {
                        rfidset.remove(tag);

                        for(Node n : found_tags_box.getChildren()) {
                            if(n.getId().equals(tag_id)) {
                                found_tags_box.getChildren().remove(n);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        tags_amount.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(tags_amount.getText()) - 1));
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });

            HBox hBox = index >= 0 ? new HBox(label) : new HBox(label, butt);
            if (even) hBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F9F9F9");
            hBox.setId(tag_id);
            hBox.setPrefHeight(25.0);
            hBox.setMinHeight(25.0);
            hBox.setMaxHeight(25.0);
            hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            hBox.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10));

            even = !even;
            this.found_tags_box.getChildren().add(hBox);
        }

        tags_amount.setText(Integer.toString(this.found_tags_box.getChildren().size()));
        this.scroll_pane.setVvalue(1.0);
    }
```

Comment: Two points - 1. You load the image every time, which, depending on the size of the image, may be time-consuming. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) states the same `Image` can be used in multiple `ImageView` instances, so you may want to try loading it only once.    2. You should look into using a `ListView` (or a `TableView`) instead of a `VBox` - both use "virtualized nodes", so only visible items are layed out - this allows performance to remain the same even with a very large number of items.

Comment: @Itai I used a ListView before but it was very slow after all items were processed. The scrolling was slow, I read something about using a VBox instead of ListView that's why I changed it. Should I change it back?

Comment: @jordibenck A `ListView` will be way more efficient that a `VBox`, assuming you use it correctly.